# MD5 Hash in AIX OS

Tags: unix, hash, md5, aix, string-hashing

Is it possible to calculate the MD5 Checksum of a string with a native command on AIX OS? On Linux system yuo can use the md5sum function, but it looks like that the command is missing on AIX OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
csum -h MD5
```

It is in bos.rte starting in AIX 5.3